# Django: Having multiple foreign keys stored in the same attribute of a model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

My question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42758439/django-getting-a-model-from-another-model) one, where the author wanted to store a reference to a model in the attribute of another model using Django's `models.ForeignKey` field type. My question is, would the *exact* same method work, if an article had multiple authors, or is something additional needed to establish this?

Comment: Then one uses a `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: This seems more like a one-to-many or many-to-one situation, if a single article has multiple authors. I'm guessing there is a field to this type of relationship as well?

Comment: if it is a one-to-many, then *every* author in the database can only write *one* article?

Comment: Hmm, true that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an article can have multiple authors and each author can have multiple articles, then you want to use a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).